# How to Post partial view to controller without updating the current view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 SPA in which bootstrap dialogs containing Partial Views are rendered on top of the main index.cshtml page.  When the submit button is clicked on the modal dialog, the partial view is posted back to the server, where it is handled by an ActionMethod on the Controller.  All this works fine, and the related model contains the data selected and entered by the user on the modal dialog.

My issue is that the ActionMethod then returns an ActionResult (the designed behaviour of ActionMethods), and I want it to return nothing.  It is essential for my application that the main page (index.cshtml) is not refreshed or replaced with another view.  Having researched this, it seems to me that the behaviour I am seeking is simply not the standard MVC pattern and I need to find some alternative way of posting the partial view that allows the model to be extracted, but does not refresh the index.cshtml page.

I'm aware that there are a number of [ActionResult types](http://www.compilemode.com/2015/06/action-result-in-asp-net-mvc.html) to choose from, all of which cause the main page of the SPA to redraw, or be replaced by other views (including an empty view) or text.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: You need to learn AJAX/Javascript

Comment: You can just return `null` (or `new EmptyResult()`)

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is called "AJAX".  This has less to do with what your action method *returns* and more to do with *how you call it from the client*.  Instead of posting a form, you want to capture your form data in JavaScript, make an AJAX POST from JavaScript code, and handle the response in that code.

Comment: You need to use AJAX if you are not already using it. You can always return empty result if you don't want to return anything from action method. You need to read about these if you haven't already. And you need to post the relevant code here so that we can understand what issue you are trying to solve

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, though returning null or new EmptyResult() results in a blank view being rendered with URL changing from http://localhost:49937/Home/ to http://localhost:49937/Home/<Name of ActionMethod>

Comment: @David, thanks, I'll get reading up on AJAX.  Am I right in thinking that I shouldn't be looking to post the model using AJAX from the PartialView, as it will only contain the data which it had when the view was rendered by the server, so instead I need to get the individual form input values and post these back with AJAX?

Comment: @user17992, Not if you are using ajax (and you have said you have a SPA app, which means that you do need to be using ajax! - I can only assume you do not understand what a Single Page Application is)